# Como interpretar los valores complejos en ANOVA

Tags: r

Estoy queriendo poder interpretar los resultados que obtuve aplicando ANOVA, pero me sale un valor complejo y muy pequeño `(Pr(>F)`, estoy viendo si puedo concluir algo o no es significativo para nada.

Van los resultados que obtuve:

```
       Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
sectorlaboral   1    786   786.5   70.64 2.52e-16 ***
Residuals     677   7537    11.1                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

respondo en lo que respecta a R, que es la temática de este espacio. Lamentablemente no hay es.stats.stackexchange.com, que sería el lugar apropiado para preguntas sobre interpretación de modelos.

Lo que llamás "valor complejo", si te entiendo bien, es un número que R reporta en notación científica y que de manera más convencional expresaríamos como 0.000000000000000252, 16 ceros antes de tu primer valor. 
Para que R no exprese ese tipo de número con notación científica podés ajustar el límite a partir del cuál la usa con la siguiente opción

```
options(scipen=999)
```

De este modo no usa notación científica hasta que tengas un número con 999 ceros antes del primer número mayor que cero. Es decir, prácticamente nunca.

Sobre al interpretación del p-value: depende de lo que estés preguntando al modelo y como le especificaste.

Asumiendo que estás haciendo un ANOVA de un factor se interpretaría que **la probabilidad de que una distribución aleatoria con la misma media verdadera que el nivel de referencia contenga el valor que tu modelo estima para sectorlaboral es muy baja**, y por o tanto podés rechazar la hipótesis de nulidad de que las medias son iguales.

Hay un debate muy interesante en la actualidad sobre el uso de p-value para pruebas de hipótesis, pero me parece que este no es el lugar para ese debate. Ojalá abran es.stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Hola Mpaladino! genial aporte! muchisimas gracias! la verdad que sería la primera en anotarme a es.stats.stackexchange.com si se crea, saludos!